# District or district

Tags: proper-nouns

> There was an evaluation by the District.

> The district employee conducted an evaluation.

> She works for the District.

Can someone confirm if these are capitalized or not? I am confused.

Comment: We'd need a full context to say confidently what should be capitalized. Is this from a novel? A human resources report? What is meant by "district" in the context? Please edit your question to supply this information. Also, check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for important tips on getting the answers you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

This is a borderline case.  On the one hand, “District” can be viewed as proper noun, referring to some particular government entity; one the other, well, district *is* a common noun.

The tiebreaker I would tend to use is, is the word being used part of the actual proper noun it is replacing.

If I were driving into New York City or Oklahoma City, I might write, “I am driving into the City.”

If I were driving into San Francisco or Seattle, from a more rural area, I might write, “I am driving into the city.”

> she works for the District

Meaning she works for the District of Columbia or the 9th Congressional District?  Capitalize.

This might be just me.